# End point APIs not showing up in API Explorer

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

I am using Java + GPE.

I have an application with 4 end point APIs. I added one more and tested in my development environment. My new api was detected by API explorer in dev environment. I then deployed to GAE but my new API doesn't show up in API explorer.

I can confirm the api classes have been deployed in GAE as I am able to access the functionality through a servlet.

Can someone please help me out ?

Regards,

Sathya

Answer (score 0):

Try to copy the two JAR files of your directory `src>enpoint-libs>libreDefEndpoint-v1>yourclassEnpoint` in the `war>WEB-INF>lib`. (Then deploy)